# Python Dict, Dynamic insert

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hello i have the following code that does an adjacency list for a graph, which print the code just fine, except when adding new values to va and vb, the older keys get overwritten. If i find that vertex 0 is adjacent to 1 and 2, i want to add both, but instead 1 is overwritten by 2. Also i tried using other insertion methods and i got error 0, which is there is no key in the dictionary with that index:

```
def caminhografo(grafo, va, vb):
    vat = vertex
    i = 0
    a = 0
    z = 0
    va = int(va)
    vb = int(vb)
    x = len(grafo.node)
    if va < vb:
        for va in range (vb+1):
            a = 0
            x = len(grafo.node)
            for a in range (x):
                if [int(va),int(a)] in grafo.node:
                    vat.adj[va] = a

    if va > vb:
        while vb > va:
            a = 0
            x = len(grafo.node)
            for a in range (x):
                if[int(vb),int(a)] in grafo.node:
                    vat.adj[vb] = a
            vb = vb - 1
    print (vat.adj)
```

How can i dynamicaly insert into the keys properly?

Here is Vertex and grafo is a graph class:

```
class graph:
  v = 0
  a = 0
  node = []

class vertex:
  adj = {}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: How does your `if va > vb` work with `while vb > va`? I'd have thought you couldn't ever enter the loop.

Comment: What type of object is `vat.adj`? `vat` appears to be a reference to a global variable `vertex`, but that doesn't help me any.

Comment: it works if the entry is in that condition, va and vb comes either one higher than the other or not at all. It's just a while doing the reverse of the first for.

Comment: @Rex No, if this code is what you actually have, that loop never happens.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, but the problem i'm getting is in the first insertion, on the first if/for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using defaultdict did the work.

```
from collections import defaultdict
```

Then instead of using the class vertex, i simply created a defaultdict(list):

```
vat = defaultdict(list)
```

After that, using append on it did the trick:

> vat[va].append(a)

It seems creating a dict of lists with brute force didn't work, as the append wouldn't happen. But using a default dictionary of lists from the import solved that problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can declare each value from `vat.adj` as a list`vat.adj[i] = []`, and do 
    `vat.adj[vb].append(a)`

note you need to initialize each item in `vat.adj` as a list for all you vertex.

```
for i in range(n):
    vat.adj[i] = []
```

Comment: If i had the following arcs:
[[0, 1], [1, 0], [0, 2], [2, 0]]

it will print:
{0: [2, 2], 1: [0, 0], 2: [0, 0]}

which means it overwritten the 0:[1,1] also it's printing the index which doesn't help.

Comment: you mean when you do `vat.adj[0].append(1)`, it will overwrite `0:[2,2]` to `0:[1,1]` ?

Comment: I get the following error if i use append:
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'append'
this is the append:
vat.adj[va].append(a)

Comment: Already did: for z in range (x):
                vat.adj[z]=0
before the first for to inicialize it with the size of the graph, and put zeroes everywhere. Still same error.

Comment: @Rex `vat.adj[z] = [] ` instead of 0, like in my post.

Comment: It prints {0: [], 1: []} as output. The append doesn't work but also doesn't give an error message. I also tried vat.adj[va].append([a]) and vat.adj[va].append(a). Nothing is inserted.